# What's the max weight a Btwin riverside 50 can hold?

Tags: weight

I've recently bought a Btwin Riverside 50 for daily commute. I weigh 94kg and usually ride with a backpack which weights around 3-5kg, I'm worried if the bike can hold my weight or the pedal might break off while standing. If the bike can't hold my weight, I want to know what modifications I can make so that it can hold my weight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual offered with the [BTWIN Riverside 50](https://www.decathlon.in/p/8399048_btwin-riverside-50-hybrid-bikes.html) (click on the bike manual tab) indicates that 100kg is the max weight for your bike. 94 + 5 = 99 so you are under the limit. Max weight limits take into account rough usage. Pedaling while standing and daily commuting is well below rough usage. The pedals on this bike have a large steel rod as the main support with a sheer strength much larger than 200 kg.

No modifications are needed.

Comment: Thank you, that's a relief :)

Comment: The bike will most certainly withstand the weight. If you don't trust the pedals check for a pair with higher weight support rating. That if you notice deformation.